# NioEventLoopGroup vs AioEventLoopGroup

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am a new comer to Netty and Java NIO. I am using Netty 4.0 RC3. I am confused by the difference between `NioEventLoopGroup` and `AioEventLoopGroup`. I see that `NioEventLoopGroup` is using Java NIO.1 selectors and channels. `AioEventLoopGroup` is using NIO.2 `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousChannelGroup`. What difference does it make from a programming & performance standpoint and when should I use which eventloopgroup? Also most examples in Netty documentation is using `NioEventLoopGroup`. If I am using Java 7, can I just replace `NioEventLoopGroup` with `AioEventLoopGroup` and expect things to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Aio* is still very new while Nio* is there for ages. We added it to Netty as we hope it will get some more improvements over the time. For now I would stay with Nio* for production.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing networking services for windows, you should use AIO(nio.2). see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx)

Unfortunately, netty removed AIO support.